# How to use utilize nested ArrayAgg in Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

These are my models:

```py
class TimeSheet(CommonModel):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(
        "employee.Employee", related_name="timesheets", on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        "core.Project", related_name="employee_timesheets", on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    timesheet_date = models.DateField()
    clock_in_time = models.DateTimeField()
    clock_out_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)


class TimesheetEquipment(CommonModel):
    equipment = models.ForeignKey(
        "equipment.Equipment",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="timesheet_equipments",
    )
    resource_code = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    resource_name = models.CharField(max_length=511)
    rate = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=30, decimal_places=decimal.ACCEPTED_DECIMAL_PLACE
    )
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=63, default="Hour")
    timesheet = models.ForeignKey(
        "timesheet.Timesheet",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="timesheet_equipments",
    )
    equipment_attachments = models.ManyToManyField(
        "costcode.ResourceCode",
        related_name="timesheet_equipments",
        blank=True,
        through="timesheet.TimesheetEquipmentAttachment",
        help_text="Other Resources to be attached with this requirement",
    )
 

class TimesheetEquipmentAttachment(models.Model):
    timesheetequipment = models.ForeignKey(
        TimesheetEquipment,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="timesheetequipmentattachments",
    )
    resource = models.ForeignKey(
        "resource_management.CostSheetResource",
        related_name="timesheetequipmentattachments",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        null=True,
    )
    resource_code = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    resource_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

This is my queryset to get all the timesheet along with its equipments:

```py
from django.db.models.functions import JSONObject
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

timesheets = (
            TimeSheet.objects.filter(project_id=project_id, timesheet_date=date)
            .select_related("employee")
            .prefetch_related(
                "timesheet_equipments",
                "timesheet_equipments__timesheetequipmentattachments",
            )
            .values("id")
            .annotate(
                timesheet_date=F("timesheet_date"),
                clock_in_time=F("clock_in_time"),
                clock_out_time=F("clock_out_time"),
                timesheet_equipments=ArrayAgg(
                    JSONObject(
                        equipment=F("timesheet_equipments__equipment_id"),
                        equipment_name=F(
                            "timesheet_equipments__equipment__equipment_name"
                        ),
                        resource_code=F("timesheet_equipments__resource_code"),
                        resource_name=F("timesheet_equipments__resource_name"),
                        rate=F("timesheet_equipments__rate"),
                        unit=F("timesheet_equipments__unit"),
                       
                      
                    ),
                    distinct=True,
                ),
            )
            .values(
                "id",
                "timesheet_date"
                "clock_in_time",
                "clock_out_time",
                "timesheet_equipments",
            )
            .order_by("-timesheet_date")
            .distinct()
        )
```

This is the queryset that i am trying to get all the timesheets along with its all equipments and each equipments should have all of there equipment attachments if exists.

But this did not worked. Any help would be highly appreciated. Or is there any other way to achieve the same.

```py
from django.db.models.functions import JSONObject
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

timesheets = (
            TimeSheet.objects.filter(project_id=project_id, timesheet_date=date)
            .select_related("employee")
            .prefetch_related(
                "timesheet_equipments",
                "timesheet_equipments__timesheetequipmentattachments",
            )
            .values("id")
            .annotate(
                timesheet_date=F("timesheet_date"),
                clock_in_time=F("clock_in_time"),
                clock_out_time=F("clock_out_time"),
                timesheet_equipments=ArrayAgg(
                    JSONObject(
                        equipment=F("timesheet_equipments__equipment_id"),
                        equipment_name=F(
                            "timesheet_equipments__equipment__equipment_name"
                        ),
                        resource_code=F("timesheet_equipments__resource_code"),
                        resource_name=F("timesheet_equipments__resource_name"),
                        rate=F("timesheet_equipments__rate"),
                        unit=F("timesheet_equipments__unit"),
                      equipment_attachments=ArrayAgg(
                            JSONObject(
                                resource_code=F(
                                    "timesheet_equipments__timesheetequipmentattachments__resource_code"
                                ),
                                resource_name=F(
                                    "timesheet_equipments__timesheetequipmentattachments__resource_name"
                                ),
                                rate=F(
                                    "timesheet_equipments__timesheetequipmentattachments__rate"
                                ),
                            ),
                            distinct=True,
                        ),
                      
                    ),
                    distinct=True,
                ),
            )
            .values(
                "id",
                "timesheet_date"
                "clock_in_time",
                "clock_out_time",
                "timesheet_equipments",
            )
            .order_by("-timesheet_date")
            .distinct()
        )
```

Here is the error that I am getting when running above code:

> FieldError: Cannot compute None('JSONObject(Value(equipment), F(timesheet_equipments__equipment_id), Value(equipment_name), F(timesheet_equipments__equipment__equipment_name), Value(resource_code), F(timesheet_equipments__resource_code), Value(resource_name), F(timesheet_equipments__resource_name), Value(rate), F(timesheet_equipments__rate), Value(unit), F(timesheet_equipments__unit), Value(equipment_duration), F(timesheet_equipments__equipment_duration), Value(total_duration), F(timesheet_equipments__total_duration), Value(note), F(timesheet_equipments__note), Value(wet_hire), F(timesheet_equipments__wet_hire), Value(equipment_attachments), ArrayAgg(JSONObject(Value(resource_code), F(timesheet_equipments__timesheetequipmentattachments__resource_code), Value(resource_name), F(timesheet_equipments__timesheetequipmentattachments__resource_name), Value(rate), F(timesheet_equipments__timesheetequipmentattachments__rate)), distinct=True))'): 'JSONObject(Value(equipment), F(timesheet_equipments__equipment_id), Value(equipment_name), F(timesheet_equipments__equipment__equipment_name), Value(resource_code), F(timesheet_equipments__resource_code), Value(resource_name), F(timesheet_equipments__resource_name), Value(rate), F(timesheet_equipments__rate), Value(unit), F(timesheet_equipments__unit), Value(equipment_duration), F(timesheet_equipments__equipment_duration), Value(total_duration), F(timesheet_equipments__total_duration), Value(note), F(timesheet_equipments__note), Value(wet_hire), F(timesheet_equipments__wet_hire), Value(equipment_attachments), ArrayAgg(JSONObject(Value(resource_code), F(timesheet_equipments__timesheetequipmentattachments__resource_code), Value(resource_name), F(timesheet_equipments__timesheetequipmentattachments__resource_name), Value(rate), F(timesheet_equipments__timesheetequipmentattachments__rate)), distinct=True))' is an aggregate

Comment: Please *don't*. Can you explain *what* you aim to do, not that much *how*? Likely you don't need an `ArrayAgg`.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem I am trying to get nested data. A timesheet object can have multiple TimesheetEquipment, so I want to get a list of objects of TimesheetEquipment in each Timesheet and at the same time TimesheetEquipment can have multiple TimesheetEquipmentAttachment, which I want to get as a list of objects in each TimesheetEquipment. Is it understandable ?